# Why can't a superpotential depend on a the hermitian conjugate of a superfield?

Tags: supersymmetry, complex-numbers

I am working through Srednicki's "Quantum Field Theory" and am at the chapter on the Minimal Supersymmetric Standard Model (MSSM).

In answer to why two higgs superfields are needed in the MSSM model, Srednicki's solutions say that "...the superpotential cannot depend on hermitian conjugates of [super]fields."

In trying to think through why this is, the best I could come up with is that any Yukawa term in the superpotential with a hermitian conjugate could either ...

1. make a vector superfield and thus not something that would be in the superpotential
2. and/or it would be a term that wouldn't be holomorphic (though I have to be honest, that my knowledge of holomorphism is very limited and shaky at best).